# reboot the PC from coding with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, dll, shutdown, reboot

how to reboot the PC from coding with VB.Net framework 2.0 or above

i also like to set timer for rebooting process.

does VB.net framework support for above process? do i need to add library or DLL file

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many way that we can shutdown or reboot the windows by coding. But I like present very easiest way and shortest way as follow.
    It’s nothing, using `“Shell”` commend.

```
' Example of rebooting PC:
' Reboot computer after timeout of 5
Shell ("Shutdown -r -t 5")  

' Switches:
'   -l  Log off profile
'   -s  Shut down computer
'   -r  Restart computer
'   -f  Force applications to close
'   -t  Set a timeout for shutdown
'   -m \\computer name (Shutdown remote computer)
'   -i  Show the Shutdown GUI
```

Answer (score 4):

Ref: [Programmatically restart computer from .NET](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/b9948921-cfdc-4fe3-b04e-c5f718646de4/)

There are different methods that you can use to shutdown/restart your computer through C# code. Following are some of them:

1. Using Win32 API.
2. Using "Shutdown" command. i.e. internally firing shutdown.exe /s

**Using "Shutdown" command:**

Code Snippet

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ShutDown", "/r")
// If immediately then use 
// System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ShutDown", "/r /t 00") 



/s = shutdown
/r = restart
/t = timed shutdown
```

Do `"shutdown/?"` at command prompt to know more about the command.

Ref: [Rebooting a Windows Box Programmatically](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/win32/tutorials/article.php/c8647/Rebooting-a-Windows-Box-Programmatically.htm)
**The Another approach is Win32 API's `ExitWindowsEx` API Function**

The first thing that we need to do is to reference the InteropServices namespace so that we can access the Windows API functions. To do this, add a new using directive at the start of the code for the form.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

put the following declaration appears within the form's class code block

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int ExitWindowsEx(uint uFlags, uint dwReason);
```

then call the this method..

```
    BOOL b = ExitWindowsEx( EWX_REBOOT|EWX_FORCE,
    SHTDN_REASON_MINOR_MAINTENANCE |
    SHTDN_REASON_FLAG_PLANNED);
```

More References:
[Shutdown, Restart, or Log Off your computer using VB.Net](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/vb/6eebdaf1-a5ce-47dd-a1e5-23e707bbf369/shutdown-restart-or-log-off-your-computer-using-vbnet.aspx)
[Simplest way to Programmatically ShutDown or Restart your System using C# or VB.NET](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/12/simplest-way-to-programmatically.html)

Answer (score 1):

See:

- http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/vb/6eebdaf1-a5ce-47dd-a1e5-23e707bbf369/shutdown-restart-or-log-off-your-computer-using-vbnet.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12815/Shutdown-Restart-VB-Net

> Code: = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ShutDown", "/r")   Here are
>   the other options:   C:>shutdown Usage: shutdown [-i | -l | -s | -r |
>   -a] [-f] [-m \computername] [-t xx] [-c "c omment"] [-d up:xx:yy]
>
> ```
>     No args                 Display this message (same as -?)
>     -i                      Display GUI interface, must be the first option
>     -l                      Log off (cannot be used with -m option)
>     -s                      Shutdown the computer
>     -r                      Shutdown and restart the computer
>     -a                      Abort a system shutdown
>     -m \\computername       Remote computer to shutdown/restart/abort
>     -t xx                   Set timeout for shutdown to xx seconds
>     -c "comment"            Shutdown comment (maximum of 127 characters)
>     -f                      Forces running applications to close without war ning
>     -d [u][p]:xx:yy         The reason code for the shutdown
>                             u is the user code
>                             p is a planned shutdown code
>                             xx is the major reason code (positive integer le ss than 256)
>                             yy is the minor reason code (positive integer le ss than 65536)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything directly in the framework, but can use p/Invoke to call [ExitWindowsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

[See the definition at pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.exitwindowsex):

```
Declare Function ExitWindowsEx Lib "user32" (ByVal dwOptions As Int32, ByVal dwReserved As Int32) As Int32
```

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
Private Sub {BTNNAME}_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles {BTNNAME}.Click
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", "-r -t 00")
End Sub
```